# Directed graph cycles and the inverse of a weighted adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, determinants

Let us view a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ as the weighted adjacency matrix of a directed graph $G$, i.e. there is an edge $i \to j$ in $G$ if $B_{ij} \neq 0$. Assume further that

- $B$ does not have self-loops, i.e., $B_{ii} = 0$ for $i \in [n]$, and
- $B$ does not have 1 as an eignevalue, i.e., $I-B$ is invertible.

I would like to claim the following two are equivalent or "all" or "almost all" $B$:

1. $B$ as a directed graph is acyclic.
2. $[B(I-B)^{-1}]_{ii} = 0$ for all $i \in [n]$.

Using the identity $[(I-B)^{-1}]_{ii} - [B(I-B)^{-1}]_{ii} = 1$, (2) is equivalent to $[(I-B)^{-1}]_{ii} = 1$ for all $i\in [n]$.

(1) implies (2) is easy: If $B$ is acyclic, we can relabel the nodes so that $B$ is, say, lower triangular. Then $(I-B)^{-1}$ will be lower triangular with unit diagonal entries.

(2) implies (1) does not seem so easy. It follows, for example, if all the nonzero entries of $B$ are positive and $B$ is small ($\| B\| <1$) so that we have the expansion $(I-B)^{-1} = I + B + B^2 + \dots $. Then, (2) is equivalent to $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (B^k)_{ii} = 0$ for all $i$ which fails if $B$ has a cycle. However, if we allow for arbitary signs, cancelations can occur.

Is (2) implies (1) in general true? (Or at least can we show  that if (1) fails and (2) holds, then the nonzero coefficients of $B$ should be the zeros of a system of polynomials, hence their location has Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb R^{|G|}$.)

Comment: But $[(I-B)^{-1}]_{ii}=1$ is already a polynomial relation on the elements of $B$, due to Cramer's formulas!

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, yes, thanks (I guess that would answer the "at least" part). But does the system of polynomials have a solution in the cyclic case. For n = 3, i.e. a single cycle it seems not possible. Let us say I am looking for a counter-example.

Answer (score 2):

Let us seek a counterexample of the form 
$$
  A:=I-B=\begin{pmatrix}
    1& 1& 1& -t\\
    1& 1& -t& 1\\
    1& -t& 1& 1\\
    -t& 1& 1& 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have $\det A=(t+1)^3(t-3)$, so we need $t\neq -1,3$.

Denote by $A_i$ the matrix obtaines from $A$ by removing the $i$th row and the $i$th column. By Cramer's formula, the equality $(A^{-1})_{ii}=1$ is equivalent to $\det A_i=\det A$. Since $\det$ is multilinear, this in turn means that the determinant of $A$ with the $(i,i)$th element replaced by $0$ should vanish. Due to the symmetry, these equations for $i=1,2,3,4$ are all equivalent and read 
$$
  0=\det\begin{pmatrix}
    0& 1& 1& -t\\
    1& 1& -t& 1\\
    1& -t& 1& 1\\
    -t& 1& 1& 1\\
  \end{pmatrix}=(t+1)^2(t^2-2t-2)
$$
So any (real) root of $t^2-2t-2=0$ does the job.

**Remark.** On the other hand, as I've already mentioned in the comments, the equation $\det A_i=\det A$ **is** a polynomial equation on the elements of $B$.

Comment: This is great, thanks! Now, is it possible to come up with an example where the cyclic directed graph is "simple", i.e., only one of each $i \to j$ or $j \to i$ is allowed to occur?